# Optimization Cost of candy

Tags: calculus, optimization

You have decided to buy candy for the trick-or-treaters and have estimated there will be 200 children coming to your door, and plan to give each children three pieces of candy. You have decided to offer Twix and 3 Musketeers. The cost of buying these two candies is
      $$C= 5T^2 + 2TM + 3M^2 + 800$$
Where T is the number of Twix and M is the number of 3 Musketeers. How many of each candy should you get to minimize the cost?

Comment: The concept in this link applies to your case, you need to take partial derivatives. http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/min_max/min_max.html

Answer (score 1):

Let be
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
&C(T,M)=5T^2 + 2TM + 3M^2 + 800\\
&\mathrm{sub}\; T+C=600
\end{align}\right.$$
We find the critical points with the lagrangian $\mathcal L(T,M,\lambda)=C(T,M)-\lambda(T+M-600)$:
$$
\nabla \mathcal L(T,M,\lambda)=\left(10 T+2 M+\lambda, 2 T+6 M+\lambda, -600+T+C\right)=(0,0,0)
$$
so that $(T,M,\lambda)=(200, 400,  -2800)$ and then $(T,M)=(200, 400)$ is the minimum.

Evaluating the function in $(200, 400)$ we find the minimum constrained value $$C(200,400)=840,800$$

Answer (score 1):

Minimize:

$C=5T^2+2TM+3M^2+800$

subject to:

$T+M=600; T,M\in \mathcal{Z^+}$

[Using Octave's builtin constrained optimization toolbox](http://pastebin.com/pL9ArNim):

$T=200, M=400$

Or, using brute force and plotting the objective function for each combination of $T,M$:

[$T=200,M=400$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4SVd.jpg)